# How to write unit test for ActionsSubject subscription in Angular Component

Tags: angular, unit-testing, testing, jasmine, ngrx

I have an Angular component that uses `ngrx` `ActionsSubject` to listen to dispatched actions. How can I write a test that can check this subscription of `ActionsSubject`?

The component looks like this:

```
export class TestComponent {

constructor(public actionsSubject: ActionsSubject) { }

  public isUpdated = false;

  public ngOnInit() {
    this.actionSubscription = this.actionsSubject.subscribe(action => {
      if (action.type === "Update") {
        this.isUpdated = true; <----- I want to test this condition
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Currently, I am dispatching update action manually:

```
  it('isUpdated should be true, when update action dispatched', () => {
    component.store.dispatch(new UpdateAction());
    expect(component.isUpdated).toEqual(true);
  });
```

It works, but I want to mock this subscription instead of calling action manually.

For example:

```
  it('isUpdated should be true, when update action dispatched', () => {
    let actionSubject = TestBed.get(ActionsSubject);
    const action = {
      type: 'Update'
    };
    actionSubject = of({ action });
    component.ngOnInit();
    fixture.detectChanges()
    expect(component.isUpdated).toEqual(true);
  });
```

Test suit looks like this

```
const action = { type: FlowActionTypes.UpdateStep }; 
const actionSub: ActionsSubject = new ActionsSubject({ action }); <-- TS not accepting 


providers: [ { provide: ActionsSubject, useValue: actionSub } <-- here I am passing as you told ]
```

But it never triggers the subscription in the component. How can I test it efficiently?

Comment: Are you providing a mock value for `ActionsSubject` for the test suite?

Comment: No, should I provide this `actionSubject = of({ action });` in provides ? But how this will be called ?

Comment: Yes, you probably should. Can you provide a full example of the test suite so I can help you better?

Comment: Actually providing a running example would be very hard. Can you help me with, providing an example of how can I pass `mock actionSubject` to TestSuit with a default `action`, so when `subscribe` will call, it will return that passed action. I tried to do that, but I think I am wrong.

```
const action = {
    type: FlowActionTypes.UpdateStep
  };
  const actionSub: ActionsSubject = new ActionsSubject({ action }); <-- TS not accepting 

providers: [
        { provide: ActionsSubject, useValue: actionSub } <-- here I am passing as you told
      ]
```

Comment: No, not a running example, just the relevant parts of the test suite, such as the parts for `TestBed.configureTestingModule`, `beforeEach`, etc, in order to see what values are being used there (related to the use case you're asking about).

Comment: That I did in last comment

Comment: It's really hard to read there :( Can you [edit] the post and add it there?

Comment: Done i have added

Comment: I'm sorry. I don't fully see the big picture in this case so I can help you :( But I think that [`provideMockStore`](https://ngrx.io/api/store/testing/provideMockStore) could help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're close as you are! 
A few things that will help you:

- ngOnInit runs the very first time you call `fixture.detectChanges` (in this case in the beforeEach) so no need to call it again in your test
- ActionsSubject inherits from BehaviorSubject, so you can treat it like any other observable
- `fixture.detectChanges` updates the html in your test, since you are looking directly at a variable on your component, no need to call
- `TestBed.get` returns `any`, it helps to cast as the service you're wanting

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { TestComponent } from './test.component';
import { ActionsSubject } from '@ngrx/store';

describe('TestComponentComponent', () => {
  let component: TestComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<TestComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    const actionSub: ActionsSubject = new ActionsSubject();

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [TestComponent],
      providers: [{ provide: ActionsSubject, useValue: actionSub }],
    })
      .compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(TestComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  fit('isUpdated should be true, when update action dispatched', () => {
    const actionSubject = TestBed.get(ActionsSubject) as ActionsSubject;
    const action = {
      type: 'Update'
    };
    actionSubject.next(action);

    expect(component.isUpdated).toEqual(true);
  });
});
```